# qt creator deplooy sqlite

Tags: qt, deployment, qt-creator

I am trying to deploy a windows application using QT and an SQLite database. I have it running without QT but how do I include the database without using a file path to my computer. I would like to deploy it on other systems. Below is an example of the path I used from db name.

```
db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("C:\\Users\\johnm\\Documents\\build-Login-Desktop_Qt_5_10_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\\release\\GbManuf.db");
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you want a portable solution, its better to use `QStandardPaths`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) that returns the directory where the executable is located

```
QString path = QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).filePath("GbManuf.db");
db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(path);
```

Comment: on windows, binaries need extra privilege to write to `Program Files` folder. Data locations can be used instead.

Comment: @sddk 
According to the route that the asker shows, it is clear that it is not in the Program Files but in Documents, so it is not necessary to have special permissions.

Comment: no, it's OP's location. The user (i mean the user who will use the app) can install the application everywhere.

Comment: @sddk The question leaves many gaps, so your answer and mine are valid, that the community decides. :D

Answer (score 1):

To store application data `QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation` can be used. [From Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html);

> Returns a directory location where persistent application data can be stored. This is an application-specific directory. To obtain a path to store data to be shared with other applications, use QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation. The returned path is never empty. On the Windows operating system, this returns the roaming path. This enum value was added in Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

For all kinds of accessible common paths, you can use [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html).
For example:

```
QString homeDirectory = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation);
```

There are many QStandardPaths available to look for: AppDataLocation, CacheLocation, DownloadLocation, etc.

Comment: if all aplications use `HomeLocation` to write their data, the home path will like a mess.

Comment: Well, duh! That's why I made it clear there are other locations to pick from as well. And you can obviously add sub folders, too.

Comment: sorry, i've read it as you recommend to use home folder, you're rigth.and also adding a folder to home can be a solution.